# which is the best plugin for wordpress mobile version website?

Tags: wordpress, mobile-website

I am developing a business website using wordpress both pc and mobile version.I want to use a plugin for mobile website creation.I have found a lot of plugins for this purpose but I am in a fix what plugin should I use. It is really confusing.

I have found mobify, WPTouch, Mobilepress, Mofuse, WPTap, Mobile smart pro

Please give me your own reasonable opinion.Thanks in advance

Edit:

Again I need a good appealing interface.So what plugin should be suitable for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WPtouch](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wptouch/) is by far the most used and most updated. It has free version but Pro for some features too. It transforms your WordPress website into an application-like theme without modifying a line of code, and offers a lot of features on the Admin panel that regarding use, look & feel and performance.

Comment: Well,WPTouch is a nice plugin I know. But WPTouch provides me mobile compatible website, not individual mobile version website.Right ? So if I will use WPTouch and use the same website for all devices will it be good ? I mean, mobile compatible or separate mobile version- which one is better ? @grosshat

Comment: @KaidulIslamSazal I think you might use WPtouch for building an individual mobile version website. You always can adapt it or get the Pro version that includes some nice features like media handling and custom menus.

Comment: I knew WPtouch is used to make the same website suitable for all devices.But is it possible to built separate version for mobile with WPtouch ?

Answer (score 1):

Which plugin does not use its own ads or links? Let me know please. I think wptouch use ads, Wapple uses its banner in mobile, Mobilepress shows the homepage like as mobile even anyone from a computer.

Comment: Well, you have said an important thing.But waht plugin should I use then to build a mobile version ?

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking to convert my Wordpress website into a mobile friendly site where I came across this Mobile Website Builder for Wordpress by DudaMobile. It works with all wordpress themes. It has three simple steps to follow- installing the dudamobile wordpress plugin, customizing your mobile website or use the site editor and publish!! Absolutely amazing.. thanks DudaMobile
DudaMobile's mobile website builder for wordpress is a great way to making your website mobile friendly. All you need to do is download and install the plugin, customise your site and publish!! I just loved it. It is simple, easy- no coding is required..this is one great thing noncoders like me loved about this plugin :) 
Check it out : http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mobile-website-builder-for-wordpress-by-dudamobile

Answer (score 1):

http://wpeasymobile.com  is a good solution to convert your current Wp install into a mobile friendly version.
There is a free version available
http://wpeasymobile.com/free-version/
The complete version is extremely flexible and well worth a look

Answer (score 0):

At last, I have used " WP Mobile detector " to achieve it.It is jquery mobile frameowork based theme which is totally customize-able. Despite of some problems.it is working for me. :) Thanks all ..